# Unable to debug $items variable in hook_menu_alter(&$items)

Tags: routes, hooks

I want to print out $items variable (the argument of hook_menu_alter) for debugging the menu properties in various pages.

I tried:

```
/**
 * Implement hook_menu_alter()
 */
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  debug($items);
  kpr($items);
}
```

cache cleared.

but $items are not printed out on the page. Any ideas?

Comment: also found the reason on the book of dgd7. mentions hook_menu_alter "is not done on every page request. The menu router table is rebuilt whenever something about the fundamental state of the Drupal application changes", such as enabling modules, defining new content types, news views, clearing cache.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not working because `hook_menu()` and `hook_menu_alter()` are invoked when the menu list is rebuild. This generally happens when a module is installed, or uninstalled, but modules can force the menu to be rebuild setting a Drupal variable, as with the following code:

```
variable_set('menu_rebuild_needed', TRUE);
```

When `hook_menu_alter()` is invoked, Drupal could also not serving a page that is visible on the browser. The function that rebuilds the menu, [menu_get_tem()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_get_item/7), is called by [menu_execute_active_handler()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_get_item/7), which is called every time Drupal bootstrap, even when an AJAX callback is invoked. In that case, the output of the debug function is not visible (nor would JavaScript get it).

In such cases, I think it is preferable to write the output to the database using `watchdog()`. The output is not immediately visible, but will be logged even when an AJAX callback is invoked.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [my_module_menu_local_tasks_alter(&$data, $router_item, $root_path)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_menu_local_tasks_alter/7) for menu tabs

Comment: I understand, but I want to inspect the whole elements of $items variable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it's not working for you (it has for me in the past). Have you double checked that the function's being run? As a last resort you can use `dd()` and then `tail -f /tmp/drupal_debug.txt` (or wherever the file is with your configuration).

Comment: yes, the function ran. just can't print out the $items.

Comment: @gilzero And any problems using `dd()`?

Comment: yes, dd() function output the $items to the drupal_debug.txt file. Thanks for that. But wondering why drupal function  kpr(), dsm() don't print it out to the page? also print_r(), var_dump() don't print it out.

Comment: to be more precise, it doesn't run every time I browse/refresh across pages.   dd() output the $item to drupal_debug.txt everytime I clear the cache:  drush cc menu

Comment: any ideas? really weird.